# Is it possible to pass a single parameter to $.when which contains two deferred objects?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I want to execute some code only when all images in a jQuery object have loaded. I can do this as follows:

```
var img1Load = $.Deferred();
$('#img1').load(img1Load.resolve);

var img2Load = $.Deferred();
$('#img2').load(img2Load.resolve);

$.when(img1Load, img2Load).done(function(){
    console.log('both imgs loaded');
});
```

This is OK, but I would like to not have to define a separate deferred object for every image. What if there are hundreds of them or if they may or may not be present on a given page? I would like to do it all at once, with something like:

```
$.when(allImagesHaveLoaded).done(function(){
    console.log('all imgs loaded');
});
```

I have tried creating an `allImagesHaveLoaded` function which iterates over the images, creating a new deferred object for each. The trouble is, if I return an array of these to be used as the parameter for a when, it doesn't work (because it's not a deferred object, it's an array of deferred object).

I fiddled around with `$.Deferred.pipe` a bit as well (to try to create a chained deferred object to pass to `when`), but that didn't appear to help.

Is there a sensible way of doing this?

Comment: JOOI - what is $(element).load() ?  It's not in the standard API as far as I can see.

Comment: It's in the jQuery documentation, [here](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/). It just binds a callback to the load event. It should not be confused with the ajax api [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/), which performs an ajax request.

Comment: ah, that one!  Of course - I thought you were _triggering_ a load of something, not binding the 'onload' callback :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a way to pass an array of deferred objects to `$.when`:

```
$.when.apply($, myArray).done(...);
```

Comment: That doesn't deal with "not have to define a separate deferred object for every image".

Comment: @lonesomeday indeed not, but I don't think there's any easy way around that. The alternative would be not using deferred objects at all (i.e. use a callback that counts the number of successful load operations).

Comment: It doesn't matter that I need to define a separate deferred object for every image so long as I am able to loop it, so this does the trick, thanks. Out of interest, how / why does it work? I can't find this in the jQuery docs...

Comment: @Spycho [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) calls a function (in this case `$.when`) by using an array: the elements of this array are used as the arguments to the function. The first argument sets the context (here `$`, the jQuery object) and the second sets the arguments. This is a native Javascript technique, not a jQuery one.

Comment: @Spycho it's not a jQuery thing, you can call _any_ function with `myfunc.apply(ctx, array)` to mean `ctx.myfunc( array_contents ...)`.  See also `.call`.

Answer (score 3):

```
var imgDefs = $("img").map(function(key, val) {
  var def = $.Deferred();
  $(val).load(def.resolve);
  return def;
}).toArray();

$.when.apply($, imgDefs).done(...);
```